# Xcode 'Build and Archive' menu item disabled

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been using the new 'Build and Archive' feature of the latest Xcode 3.2.3.  I like it.

Now I noticed that it is always disabled for some reason.  I can't seem to figure out what I changed to cause this.

Comment: This may help you [Change The deployment target to iOS Device](http://way2ios.com/development/ios-development-2/iphone-2/error-while-creating-ipa-file-in-xcode-4-and-xcode-4-2/)

Answer (score 695, accepted):

[image: iOS Device is selected and Archive is enabled]

Build configiuration setting needs to be an "iOS Device" (or any specific device if connected) to activate "Product → Archive" menu item. For some strange reason when any kind of iOS Simulator is selected, Archive is greyed out.

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  I am set to 'Device'.

Comment: Worked for me. UI frustrations are the worst.

Comment: Argh that was a needless waisted half hour

Comment: This setting is under project>set active SDK

Comment: In Xcode3 yes, it's there. In Xcode4 you can select correct target near scheme selection in a toolbar.

Comment: Punjabi: O tawadi khaer ho jay...
English: blown away.... (not a perfect translation but close)

Comment: I keep faling for this one over and over: Why is my Archive menu disabled!? Google -> Stack Overflow -> Oh, duh!

Comment: Why? Because Apple almost only does user experience testing for non-developers, clearly.

Comment: What a relief it's not some XCode nightmare!  Thanks!

Comment: The reason has something to do with building active architectures vs all architectures or something like that.  You need a device to get an ARM architecture...   Something along those lines.

Comment: Wish this screenshot contained the full menu because I can't find this.

Comment: What exactly can't you find? iOS device or another real device (your iPhone, iPod touch or iPad) must be selected in target selector. And "Archive" action is in the Xcode "Product" menu.

Answer (score 5):

in my case, the archive checkbox was unchecked. =/ strange

[image: under edit scheme]

Answer (score 2):

in `xcode 10.2`:
make your project on `Generic ios devices` tab and go to `product>archive`to archive your project after if you want to see all your archived history go to `windows>organizer`tap .

Answer (score 2):

I Faced the same issue.

This is how I solved it.

Go to device list, and select `any ios device`

then go to the `product` menu, `archive` option should be `active/enabled` now.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create an Executable File in your project folder... If you start with a fresh project there are NO executable projects, only what you create, be it a .cpp or a .m you need an executable in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Alexander Babaev said , when I had this problem it was because for some reason the build configuration was set to MAC 64 bit (dont know how it got there...) , returned it to IOS and it got enabled again.

Comment: XCode seems to have several things that can cause your schemes to "forget" their targets, reverting to Mac 64 bit.  Editing schemes and returning the target to iOS like you said always does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the application_tools_1.1.dmg

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your project scheme in "manage schemes …"  and then click "autocreate schemes now" in the manage schemes window. This gives back the archive option.

Answer (score 0):

Had been messing around with this for quite some time too. Don't forget to click on 'Validate Settings' at the bottom after you've checked the 'Prerendered' tickbox in the summary tab. And if you're deploying your app to the iPhone or iPad, make sure you delete the app first and then build it again. Otherwise your icons will still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Quitting and relaunching XCode sometimes helps. It usually does for me, if choosing an iOS device doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to add a ios device then go to product on the top then click it after that you can get enadled Archive option .**