# 'Build for Archiving ' option is not active for build

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XCode ‘Build and Archive’ menu item disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087089/xcode-build-and-archive-menu-item-disabled)

Can some one help me I can't find `Build for Archiving` option for build Archive of my app.

Comment: Please search **before** posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply go to Product -> Build For -> Archiving.

If this is not available (if the text is in grey), make sure you didn't select a simulator on the top left of the main window, but "iOS Device".

Answer (score 0):

Select "iOS device" not the simulator and it will get active.